# Organizing diagrams in Enterprise Architect

Tags: layout, diagram, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to somehow organize my diagrams in Enterprise Architect? We're starting having too many of them, with each diagram containing many elements. Is creating a separate folder for each diagram the only solution to make the model easier to see through, or is there a more elegant layout for that?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: All right, acknowledged; my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, [Model Views will help you to create distinct viewpoints representing your entities from different perspectives](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/navigate_search_and_trace/model_views.html).

If you stick to the architecture principles of [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) and [modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming), you should be able to split up very big diagrams into smaller ones. After all, their role is to give you an idea of how things are coupled and work together, but also to abstract from things that are not really relevant in the given context of the diagram. Diagrams are not meant to just visualize *all* elements in one big picture.

You can create package structures that are pretty complex and then use the model search. You can also put [hyperlink elements for easier navigation between diagrams](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_languages/hyperlinks_between_diagrams.html).

If you have to split up elements into different diagrams (which then go into different packages) EA will preserve their relationships and you can review them at any time using the [traceability view](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/navigate_search_and_trace/hierarchy.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would also have a look at the EA options for [composite diagrams](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/modeling_languages/compositeelements.html). This should help you re-organise a Single System into a number of Composite Sub-Systems.

Comment: Yes, they are helpful sometimes. Downside is, they don't appear in an RTF report afaik.

Answer (score 3):

To start modeling an application architecture, you can use a perspective based approach or a view modeling perspectives approach to describe your system. For example use the [4+1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746685/observer) view based approach to collect your Logical, Development, NonFunctional and Requirements perspective. Organize it according the mentioned dimmensions or decompose each dimmension by the application modules and have a conceptual view to have a global view of your system.

To start with a model of an enteprise architecture use for example the togaf dimensions or zachman framework layers and dimmensions

Answer (score 2):

You can use several packages to categorize your content. 
I use to make a package diagram on top level which dynamically updates its contents depending on underlying packages (simply drag & drop the packages in the package diagram)
and the content (e.g. for activity diagrams) like entry or final can be saved in a *common* package.

Unfortunately there is no possibility yet (version 10 build 1004) to customize the packages e.g. with colors. So that a *common* packages could have a distinct color.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to make Project Browser more organized is to create one package named "Diagram's elements" and drag all the diagram element there.
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

There's some good advice in [this blog](http://community.sparxsystems.com/white-papers/622-94project-documentation-with-enterprise-architect) on the Sparx Systems (the EA publisher) website.